# React - The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to get the price of my token but I hae this error :

```
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.  TS2362
```

hooks.ts :

```
export const usePriceCakeBusd = async () => {
      const {
        data: { data },
      } = await axios.get(
          "https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82"
      );
      return (parseFloat(data.price) || 0.0).toFixed(3);
    };
```

file.tsx :

```
    const cakePrice = usePricecakeBusd()
    
    <Label>~${(CAKEPrice * cakeBalance).toFixed(2)}</Label>
```

I don't understand why my variable CAKEPrice is not number ?

Comment: I think there are some problems with the code. Although, the main error is that Typescript is treating `<Label>` as a `type` instead of a JSX Element. Is this functions supposed to be a custom hook or a React component?

Comment: @Jappan yes the function usePriceCakeBusd is in hook.ts